# Error with pg sql-lite adapter in Sinatra

Tags: sqlite, postgresql

I'm having a problem connecting to the development database in Sinatra. The guy that is doing the back end is in New York and is not available at the moment. I'm more familiar with the front end and was wondering, is there something simple that I am missing?

The production database connects, ok, but when I try launching it in development mode I get a bunch of errors in the terminal. I also tried using launching thin using port 5432 with no success.

Any Ideas?  *edit* added models.rb below

**Terminal**

```
mdb|moreButton⚡ ⇒ ruby app.rb   
/Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@sinatra/gems/data_objects-0.10.10/lib/data_objects/connection.rb:79:in `initialize': could not connect to server: Connection     refused (DataObjects::ConnectionError)
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (fe80::1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
    from /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@sinatra/gems/data_objects-0.10.10/lib/data_objects/connection.rb:79:in `new'
    from /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@sinatra/gems/data_objects-0.10.10/lib/data_objects/pooling.rb:181:in `block in new'
    from <internal:prelude>:10:in `synchronize'
    from /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@sinatra/gems/data_objects-0.10.10/lib/data_objects/pooling.rb:176:in `new'
    from /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@sinatra/gems/data_objects-0.10.10/lib/data_objects/pooling.rb:121:in `new'
    from /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@sinatra/gems/data_objects-0.10.10/lib/data_objects/connection.rb:68:in `new'
    from /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@sinatra/gems/dm-do-adapter-1.2.0/lib/dm-do-adapter/adapter.rb:251:in `open_connection'
    from /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@sinatra/gems/dm-transactions-1.2.0/lib/dm-transactions/adapters/dm-do-adapter.rb:69:in `open_connection'
    from /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@sinatra/gems/dm-do-adapter-1.2.0/lib/dm-do-adapter/adapter.rb:276:in `with_connection'
    from /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@sinatra/gems/dm-do-adapter-1.2.0/lib/dm-do-adapter/adapter.rb:33:in `select'
    from /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@sinatra/gems/dm-migrations-1.2.0/lib/dm-migrations/adapters/dm-postgres-adapter.rb:45:in `schema_name'
    from /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@sinatra/gems/dm-migrations-1.2.0/lib/dm-migrations/adapters/dm-do-adapter.rb:26:in `storage_exists?'
    from /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@sinatra/gems/dm-migrations-1.2.0/lib/dm-migrations/auto_migration.rb:65:in `storage_exists?'
    from /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@sinatra/gems/dm-migrations-1.2.0/lib/dm-migrations/auto_migration.rb:120:in `storage_exists?'
    from /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@sinatra/gems/dm-constraints-1.2.0/lib/data_mapper/constraints/migrations/model.rb:22:in `auto_migrate_constraints_down'
    from /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@sinatra/gems/dm-constraints-1.2.0/lib/data_mapper/constraints/migrations/singleton_methods.rb:39:in `block in     auto_migrate_constraints_down'
    from /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@sinatra/gems/dm-core-1.2.0/lib/dm-core/support/descendant_set.rb:64:in `block in each'
    from /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@sinatra/gems/dm-core-1.2.0/lib/dm-core/support/subject_set.rb:210:in `block in each'
    from /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@sinatra/gems/dm-core-1.2.0/lib/dm-core/support/ordered_set.rb:319:in `block in each'
    from /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@sinatra/gems/dm-core-1.2.0/lib/dm-core/support/ordered_set.rb:319:in `each'
    from /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@sinatra/gems/dm-core-1.2.0/lib/dm-core/support/ordered_set.rb:319:in `each'
    from /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@sinatra/gems/dm-core-1.2.0/lib/dm-core/support/subject_set.rb:210:in `each'
    from /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@sinatra/gems/dm-core-1.2.0/lib/dm-core/support/descendant_set.rb:63:in `each'
    from /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@sinatra/gems/dm-constraints-1.2.0/lib/data_mapper/constraints/migrations/singleton_methods.rb:38:in     `auto_migrate_constraints_down'
    from /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@sinatra/gems/dm-constraints-1.2.0/lib/data_mapper/constraints/migrations/singleton_methods.rb:7:in `auto_migrate!'
    from /Users/adam/Git/mdb/models.rb:403:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/adam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /Users/adam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from app.rb:1:in `<main>'
```

**My Gemset**

```
mdb|moreButton⚡ ⇒ gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

addressable (2.2.8)
backports (2.6.4, 2.6.1)
bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1)
bundler (1.1.5)
daemons (1.1.9)
data_mapper (1.2.0)
data_objects (0.10.10, 0.10.8)
dm-adjust (1.2.0)
dm-aggregates (1.2.0)
dm-constraints (1.2.0)
dm-core (1.2.0)
dm-do-adapter (1.2.0)
dm-migrations (1.2.0)
dm-postgres-adapter (1.2.0)
dm-serializer (1.2.2, 1.2.1)
dm-sqlite-adapter (1.2.0)
dm-timestamps (1.2.0)
dm-transactions (1.2.0)
dm-types (1.2.2, 1.2.1)
dm-validations (1.2.0)
do_postgres (0.10.10, 0.10.8)
do_sqlite3 (0.10.10, 0.10.8)
eventmachine (1.0.0, 0.12.10)
fastercsv (1.5.5)
hpricot (0.8.6)
json (1.7.5, 1.6.7)
json_pure (1.7.5, 1.6.7)
mime-types (1.19)
multi_json (1.3.6, 1.0.4)
multimap (1.1.2)
rack (1.4.1)
rack-protection (1.2.0)
rack-test (0.6.2, 0.6.1)
rake (0.9.2.2)
rest-client (1.6.7)
rubygems-bundler (1.0.3)
rvm (1.11.3.5)
sass (3.2.1)
shotgun (0.9)
sinatra (1.3.3, 1.3.2)
sinatra-contrib (1.3.1)
sinatra-reloader (1.0)
stringex (1.4.0, 1.3.3)
thin (1.5.0)
tilt (1.3.3)
time-ago-in-words (0.1.2)
uuidtools (2.1.3, 2.1.2)
```

**app.rb gemfile**

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
gem 'sinatra'
gem 'data_mapper'
gem 'hpricot'
gem 'dm-core'
gem 'json'
gem 'dm-postgres-adapter'
gem 'dm-adjust'
gem 'time-ago-in-words'
gem 'sass'
gem 'rest-client'
gem 'multimap'

group :development do
  gem "dm-sqlite-adapter"
  gem 'sinatra-reloader'
end
```

**models.rb**

```
if $development
    DataMapper.setup(:default, "postgres://localhost/mistakesdb_default")
else
    DataMapper.setup(:default, "postgres://giberish:giberish@ec2-23-21-209-147.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/giberish")
end
DataMapper.finalize
if $development
    #DataMapper.auto_upgrade!
    DataMapper.auto_migrate!
else
    DataMapper.auto_upgrade!
    #DataMapper.auto_migrate!
end

###### required.rb ######
$development = File.exists?('/Users/adam')

##### Top of app.rb #####
require "./models.rb"
require "./required.rb"
require "sinatra"
require "sass"
require "sinatra/reloader" if $development
require "time-ago-in-words"
require "rest_client"
require "multimap"
```

Comment: What does your database.yml file look like (filtering any passwords, of course)?  The trace looks like its trying to connect to a PostgreSQL database, not SQL Lite. If production mode works, compare your production database configuration to your development configuration and that might shed some light on the problem.

Comment: I don't have a database.yml file in my repo... I did find some more db info located in models.rb though. Also the production db is on Heroku if that helps.

Comment: Oh snap... I just realized this after pasting in the code above... is the local database setup for pg? If so can I just download postgress.app gui and create a blank database called "mistakesdb_default"?

Comment: Thats right. I haven't personally tried postgress.app, but after a quick glance it looks like it would do the trick.  If you do go with a different installer, a good gui postgres administration utility is pgAdmin - http://www.pgadmin.org/

Comment: I just tried the postgres.app for osx and added a new database and it's working. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In development mode DataMapper is trying to connect to a local PostgreSQL database called mistakesdb_default.  It appears that you don't have a local postgres install running at all, hence the "connection refused" error.  Depending on your operating system, you might be able to find an easy postgres installer at http://www.enterprisedb.com/.

Comment: I guess that makes a lot of sense! I'll get PostresSQL installed and give it another try. I need to learn more about databases very soon!
Thanks!!